# How to install RMongo package in R

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I have installed R 3.1.2. I want to install `RMongo` package so that I can access my mongoDB database.I have downloaded `RMongo-master.zip` file from GitHub. But I am not able to install this package. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

To install packages from github, first install and load the `devtools` package:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
```

Then use [`install_github`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/devtools/docs/install_github).

```
install_github("Rmongo", "tc")
```

---

Though in this case, `Rmongo` is on CRAN, so you can just do:

```
install.packages("RMongo") //name of package is case sensitive
```

Comment: So I have to write the queries in R Gui or R studio??

Comment: Because when I am writing the 1st command i.e install.packages("devtools") in R Gui it shows the below errors i.e "Warning: unable to access index for repository http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.1" and
"Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.1"

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use R GUI or RStudio or any other IDE.  That warning occurs when R cannot access the internet (as well as when CRAN is offline).  Do you have internet access on your machine? Are you on a corporate network where access is being blocked?  In the former case, um, plug in the network cable.  In the latter case, try `setInternet2()` (Windows only), or speak to your network admin.

Comment: The `install_github` call failed to me (RStudio 1.1.436, R 3.4.4), I had to switch it to `install_github("tc/Rmongo")`

Answer (score 1):

I have used below command. it's worked for me.

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)
install_github("tc/Rmongo")
```

Answer (score -3):

Try...
    install_github("tc/RMongo")